# Regex - Amend lines and escape line breaks to match a specific tab-delimited pattern

Tags: regex, text, awk, sed, grep

I have a supposedly 'tab-delimited' file with 4 columns contained in 5 million lines. The file currently looks like this:

[image]

Tried selecting only the lines that started with a number but discovered that it did not help much as there were still some irregular lines which also started with numbers

I am trying to clean up the file but I can't figure out a way of escaping the line breaks contained in the third column. The final output should be such that each line would contain four columns of tab-delimited text. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Post your examples as *text*, not as a *picture*

Comment: @hek2mgl sorry I tried pasting as text but the tabs were not displaying properly

Comment: probably copy paste `head -6 file | cat -e` to question.. to preserve space, use the `{}` formatting icon in editing window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is *field*-based, `awk` is probably the best choice.

#### If there can be at most *1* record-internal line break:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF<4 { thisLine=$0; getline; $0 = thisLine " " $0 } 1' file
```

- `-F'\t'` tells `awk` to split each input line into fields by tabs.
- `NF<4` is a pattern (condition) that only evaluates to true if the number of fields (`NF`) is less than 4, which in your case implies an input line with an internal line break;
  the associated action (the `{...}` block) is only executed if the pattern evaluates to true.
- `thisLine=$0; getline` saves the current input line (`$0`) in variable `thisLine`, and the reads the *next* line using the built-in `getline` function (which automatically stores *that* in `$0`).

  - Note: *Generally*, [`getline` is to be avoided](http://awk.info/?tip/getline), but its use here is justified.
- `$0 = thisLine " " $0` simply concatenates the current and the next line with an intervening space and stores the result in `$0`.
- `1`, the next pattern (without an associated action), is a common shorthand for simply printing the (potentially modified) input line, as contained in `$0`.

---

#### If there can be *multiple* record-internal line breaks:

```
awk -F'\t' '
NF<4 { combined = combined (combined == "" ? "" : " ") $0; next }
combined != "" { print combined; combined = "" }
1
END { if (combined != "") print combined }
' file
```

- An open-ended number of adjacent lines that have fewer than 4 fields must now be combined *line by line* (`combined = combined (combined == "" ? "" : " ") $0`).
- Reaching a 4-field record implies that a previous multi-line record, if any (`combined != ""`), is now complete, and must be printed (and the `combined` variable reset) (`{ print combined; combined = "" }`), before printing the current record (`1`).
- Finally, the `END` block ensures that if the *last* record happened to be a multi-line record, it is also printed.

Comment: thanks for the detailed feedback on the subject, i have run the script and it helped revealed more challenges with the data.....There are some missing fields....tried using the second script to address this issue but no joy

Comment: Your sample data - unlike your description of the problem - suggests that there are line breaks not only in the 3rd field, but in/between others too. If that's the case, my script won't help.